# The train arrives at/in Chicago

Tags: grammar

1. The train arrives at Chicago.
2. The train arrives in Chicago.

---

Chicago is a big city, so we use 'in' before a big city. However, what about the sentences above? Do we have to use 'at' or 'in'? If we think of a particular point, we use 'at'. As the train arrives at a particular point, do we have to use 'at' here? Later the train will leave Chicago. Or are both prepositions possible?

Comment: Both are possible, but I would reserve *at* for use when Chicago is part of an itinerary instead of the sole destination. Still, you could use *in* for that purpose as well.

Comment: This is a duplicate of a question you [asked an hour before](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/209529/37173) about airplanes. There are also multiple previous questions about this topic. [This one for example](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/168170/37173)

Comment: The train would be **in** Chicago for quite some time before it arrives **at** *the* Chicago *terminal.*